# How to solve the html parser error on Joomla site?

Tags: php, xml, ubuntu, joomla

Hy people, I recently migrated my site to new server and now I am getting an error whenever I go to my front page.

http://144.130.57.197/MonashHealthNew/beta.monashhealth.org/en/

Here is the error which I am getting and I have no clue about it:

> parser = xml_parser_create($encoding); xml_set_object($this->parser, &$this); xml_parser_set_option($this->parser, XML_OPTION_CASE_FOLDING, 0); xml_parser_set_option($this->parser, XML_OPTION_SKIP_WHITE, 1); xml_parser_set_option($this->parser, XML_OPTION_TARGET_ENCODING, 'UTF-8'); xml_set_element_handler($this->parser, "start_element", "stop_element"); xml_set_character_data_handler($this->parser, "char_data"); } function force_to_array() { for ($i = 0; $i < func_num_args(); $i++) { $this->force_to_array[] = func_get_arg($i); } } /* Parse XML data, storing it in the instance variable; returns false if the data cannot be parsed. */ function parse($data) { $this->tree = array(); if (!xml_parse($this->parser, $data, 1)) { $this->error = "xml parse error: " . xml_error_string(xml_get_error_code($this->parser)) . " on line ".xml_get_current_line_number($this->parser); return false; } return $this->tree[0]["content"]; } function parse_file($file) { $fp = @fopen($file, "r"); if (!$fp) { user_error("unable to open file: '$file'"); return false; } while ($data = fread($fp, 4096)) { if (!xml_parse($this->parser, $data, feof($fp))) { user_error("xml parse error: " . xml_error_string(xml_get_error_code($this->parser)) . " on line " . xml_get_current_line_number($this->parser)); } } fclose($fp); return $this->tree[0]["content"]; } function encode_as_xml($value) { if (is_array($value)) { reset($value); $out = ''; while (list($key,$val) = each($value)) { if (is_array($val) && isset($val[0])) { reset($val); while (list(,$item) = each($val)) { $out .= "".xml_simple::encode_as_xml($item).""; } } else { $out .= "".xml_simple::encode_as_xml($val).""; } } return $out; } else { return htmlspecialchars($value); } } function start_element($parser, $name, $attrs) { array_unshift($this->tree, array("name" => $name)); } function stop_element($parser, $name) { if ($name != $this->tree[0]["name"]) die("incorrect nesting"); if (count($this->tree) > 1) { $elem = array_shift($this->tree); if (isset($this->tree[0]["content"][$elem["name"]])) { if (is_array($this->tree[0]["content"][$elem["name"]]) && isset($this->tree[0]["content"][$elem["name"]][0])) { array_push($this->tree[0]["content"][$elem["name"]], $elem["content"]); } else { $this->tree[0]["content"][$elem["name"]] = array($this->tree[0]["content"][$elem["name"]],$elem["content"]); } } else { if (in_array($elem["name"],$this->force_to_array)) { $this->tree[0]["content"][$elem["name"]] = array($elem["content"]); } else { if (!isset($elem["content"])) $elem["content"] = ""; $this->tree[0]["content"][$elem["name"]] = $elem["content"]; } } } } function char_data($parser, $data) { # don't add a string to non-string data if (!is_string($this->tree[0]["content"]) && !preg_match("/\S/", $data)) return; $this->tree[0]["content"] .= $data; } }

However other pages of my site are working perfect. You can take a look by visiting this page
http://144.130.57.197/MonashHealthNew/beta.monashhealth.org/en/contact-us

I would appreciate any type of help from you. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think xml-simple.php is the problem. If you view the source (on the homepage http://144.130.57.197/MonashHealthNew/beta.monashhealth.org/en/) it's start with:

```
<?
```

/* xml-simple.php

Can you change this to (in the xml-simple.php file)?

```
<?php
```

/* xml-simple.php

I think ' short_open_tag' is disabled in the config (php.ini)

Comment: changed. Now 500 error is coming.
Here is the link
http://imgur.com/a/mjtmC

Comment: You can check the error logs for the 500 error.

But i see no errors on the homepage anymore, fixed?
http://144.130.57.197/MonashHealthNew/beta.monashhealth.org/en/

Comment: I have disable the module which was showing 500 error. thanks